# GNOME Shell Overview animation is slow on my NVIDIA 320M

Tags: nvidia, gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on my MacBook Air 11" (late 2010 model 3,1). Compiz runs fine, as well as most of GNOME Shell's animations.

The animation for switching to and from GNOME Shell overview is just very slow. Unfortunately, it's the most common animation on Shell.

I already applied

```
cd ~/gnome-shell/source/gnome-shell
curl http://bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=157326 > shell-animations-nvidia.patch
git am shell-animations-nvidia.pat
```

that I found from http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/SwatList , but the issue's still here.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**
Apparently, it's an NVIDIA driver bug, which has something to do with the message tray. Is this correct? How do I go around this issue?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are you using the default theme? A lot of custom themes I've tried have had inexplicably low frame-rates during that animation.

Comment: Using the default theme

Comment: The NVIDIA driver bug is confirmed, btw

Answer (score 0):

After using the Gnome-Shell built from source on 10.10 for about a month, compiling daily, the last few weeks builds have been going from normal to slow on my Nvidia card with the nvidia-current driver.

The experimental driver works great for me on 11.04 ALPHA

Comment: Which experimental driver? Link please :)

Comment: It is the nouveau driver with experimental 3D. In Natty they can be installed under drivers. Might even be default by now

http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/