# Will the MacBook Pro Early 2011 work better with Ubuntu than the Air Late 2010?

Tags: macbook, apple

I got this late 2010 11" MacBook Air. I'm having issues with NVIDIA graphics, [especially with GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20864/gnome-shell-overview-animation-is-slow-on-my-nvidia-320m).

I'm thinking about selling this to switch to the new MacBook Pro, particularly the entry level 13" ([see specs here](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-13inch.html)), because of the Intel HD Graphics 3000. I assume that it will be more FOSS-friendly.

I just want to point out that there are non-negotiable reasons why I'm keeping an Apple hardware at the moment, so let's keep this on topic.

- Will the MacBook Pro Early 2011 work better with Ubuntu than the Air Late 2010?
- Any other factors than the graphics hardware?
- Should we expect better NVIDIA graphics anytime soon?

Answer (score 1):

Check the hardware against the [Canonical component catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog). That might help you out.